# Semantic UI - Resize tab/div to fit dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui but this may be a more general question. I have created a set of tabs (see below). I then dynamically load the tabs with a table. The tables are wider than the tabs (see below) - is there a way to get the tab to resize to the table? This is only an issue on smaller (mobile) devices. I thought maybe jQuery could be used but can't seem to get anything to work.

**Edit**: added snippet but not sure it's possible to see the issue in the snippet tool

**Edit2**: Added a before and after jQuery .width() console log to snippet. The width maxes out to 480 no matter what value I put in.

```
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
  <a class="active item" data-tab="Fixtures" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">Fixtures</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="Standings" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">Standings</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="Stats" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">Stats</a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached active tab segment" data-tab="Fixtures">
  <div id="showFixtures"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="Standings">
  <div id="showStandings"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="Stats">
  Stats
</div>
```

```js
var jData = [{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "cars": "Ford",
  "Longer Title": "Longer text",
  "Longer Title2": "Longer text",
  "Longer Title3": "Longer text",
  "Longer Title2a": "Longer text"
}];

console.log("Before: " + $('.ui.menu').width());

$('.ui.menu').width(800);


console.log("After: " + $('.ui.menu').width());

$('.menu .item')
  .tab();
div_id = "showFixtures";
CreateTableFromJSON(jData, div_id)

function CreateTableFromJSON(jData, div_id) {
  // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER.
  var col = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < jData.length; i++) {
    for (var key in jData[i]) {
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }

  // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  table.id = "dp";
  table.className = "ui collapsing striped blue table unstackable";

  var thead = table.appendChild(document.createElement("thead"));

  var tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));

  var thr = thead.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.className = "collapsing";
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    thr.appendChild(th);
  }

  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
  for (var i = 0; i < jData.length; i++) {

    var tr = tbody.insertRow(-1);

    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      tabCell.className = "collapsing";
      tabCell.innerHTML = jData[i][col[j]];
    }
  }

  // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
  var divContainer = document.getElementById(div_id);
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
    <a class="active item" data-tab="Fixtures" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">Fixtures</a>
    <a class="item" data-tab="Standings" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">Standings</a>
    <a class="item" data-tab="Stats" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">Stats</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui bottom attached active tab segment" data-tab="Fixtures">
    <div id="showFixtures"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="Standings">
    <div id="showStandings"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="Stats">
    Stats
  </div>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: try to add all your code here to make a runnable snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able do this with jQuery using [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/). For example, if you wanted to resize the tabs when the "Fixtures" tab is clicked you could do:

```
$('.item[data-tab="Fixtures"]').click(function() {
  $('.ui.menu').width($('#showFixtures').width());
}
```

Comment: I tried that but when I log to console it saying ui.menu width is undefined

Comment: I've added an id to various classes and then just change the width but to no effect. Chrome inspector tells me the class is "ui bottom attached active tab segment" but changing that does not 'stick'.